# Find pairs of elements in Vector

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have the following vector. `V = {1,2,3,4}`
I want to find all pairs of elements. In total i'll have **K(K-1)/2** pairs of elements.

---

pairs = {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {2,3}, {2,4}, {3,4}.

```
Formula: K(K-1)/2 = 4(4-1)/2 = 6 pairs
```

---

What should be the pseudo-code of this algorithm.

---

Thank you dasblinkenlight for your help. I wrote the code, it might help someone for the future:

pseudo-code : dasblinkenlight

```
for i in [0..N)
    pair.first = data[i]      // Set the first element
    for j in (i..N)
        pair.second = data[j] // Set the second element
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(4);
    typedef pair<int,int> pairs;
    pairs p;
    vector<pairs> pVec;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size();i++)
    {
        p.first = v[i]; // Set the first element
        for(size_t j = i+1; j < v.size();j++)
        {
            p.second = v[j];// Set the second element
            pVec.push_back(p); // Add p to vector
        }
    }

    // Print pairs 
    for(size_t i = 0; i < pVec.size();i++)
    {
        cout <<"{"<< pVec[i].first <<"  "<<pVec[i].second <<"}" <<", ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the general thoughts on how to do it:

- There are `N` candidates for the first member of the pair
- When member `k` is chosen to be the first member of the pair, there are `N-k` candidates for the second member of the pair
- You can generate all pairs using two *nested* loops
- You can prove that the total number of pairs is `N*(N-1)/2` using the [formula for the sum of an arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) with the step of `1`.

Here is how you can do it with two loops:

```
for i in [0..N)
    pair.first = data[i]      // Set the first element
    for j in (i..N)
        pair.second = data[j] // Set the second element
```

Note: The above code uses math notation for intervals, where square brackets denote inclusion of the corresponding end in the interval, and the round parentheses denote exclusion of the corresponding end.

Comment: So let me see. Every time after I assign data[j] to **pair.second** I add pair to a vector of pairs right?

Comment: @ring0 Yes, you're right - I edited the first loop to use `i`. The check for `first != second` is not necessary, because `j` starts at `i+1` (I used math notation for intervals).

Comment: @HaniGoc Yes, once you assign `pair.second`, the pair is complete and ready for use. You can add it to a vector, print it out, or do anything else that you wish to do with that pair.